# Android working with realm

Tags: android, realm

I have this model -

```
public class ItemsModel extends RealmObject {
private long id;
private String itemName;
private int itemCode;
private int itemPrice;
private int itemImage;
private int itemStock;
private int itemAmount;
private int discount;
private int total;
private boolean isSelected = false;
private int seller;

public ItemsModel() {
}
```

and this model -

```
public class CartModel extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private int cartId;
private RealmList<ItemsModel> itemsModels;

public CartModel() {
}
```

I saves items in ItemsModel and want to save the items selected in realmlist inside the CartModel, but there is some problems with that -

even when I'm trying to change the id before - it inserted to the main model(ItemsModel) and not to the ItemsList in the CartModel -

```
  ItemsModel i = new ItemsModel();
        i.setId(itemsModelRealmList.size());
        i.setSeller(registerModels.getRegisterMainSeller());
        i.setItemCode(item.getItemCode());
        i.setItemPrice(item.getItemPrice());
        i.setItemImage(item.getItemImage());
        i.setItemName(item.getItemName());

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.where(CartModel.class).findFirst().getItemsModels().add(i);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

if I'm trying to insert to the list inside the cart the same object from ItemsModel - the recyclerview act like they are one object.

thanks

Comment: `implements serializable` in CartModel.java

Comment: Why is items model id not marked with primary key?

Comment: I removed, and returned ..
I thought maybe that was the reason